# jQuery select element containing a link that contains any element of array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to work out a complicated jQuery selection. I have an array, and I need to select `div.foo` that contains a link `a.bar` and the link's `href` contains any of the strings in the array.

For example:

```
<html>
<div class=foo>
  some text
  <a class=bar href=example.com?q=widget&id=23456789>search</a>
</div>
</html>
```

and jScript

```
widgets[0]='12345678';
widgets[1]='23456789';
widgets[2]='34567890';
```

I want to highlight this div because the query string contains `23456789` which is one of the elements in `widgets[]`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.foo > a.bar[href*=23456789');
```

> select all `a` which contains '23456789' in
>   the href attributes with the bar class
>   which are direct descendant of all div
>   with a class foo.

```
for (num in widgets)
{
    $('div.foo > a.bar[href*=' + num + ']').doSomething();
}
```

Comment: for (*num* in widgets) ... :)

Comment: .dosomething() applies to a.bar. I needed to add .parent() to apply to div.foo, but this is what I was looking for.

Thanks!